# How do I deploy an Android MonoGame game to an Android phone?

Tags: android, windows-phone-8, deployment, monogame

I recently created a game using XNA 4.0 for Windows Phone. I was able to deploy it to a physical device running Windows Phone 8 by connecting the device to my computer and deploying the project's XAP file with Windows Phone Application Deployment 8.1. I've now ported the game to MonoGame for Android and want to deploy it to a Samsung phone running Android 4.4.4. I was wondering how I would be able to do this. I see that the project folder contains an APK file rather an XAP file. Can I deploy this to the device in order to deploy the game? If so, what program would I use to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need a Xamarin liscence to deploy your Android Monogame application. 
Check out this example that shows what you want to do.
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/game_development/monogame/introduction/part1/

Xamarin Studio actually cost 25 $ / month.
But I found that they have a free starter edition if you want to look up. It seems to not be limited. 
https://xamarin.com/starter

Comment: I'm currently using Xamarin Studio with a free trial of Business Edition. I've noticed that there is an option in the "Run" menu that says "Upload to device". Do you know if that's what I need to be able to deploy the game to a connected phone?

Comment: @Ben It might be. Try it.